# Linux installed on external HDD won't boot

Tags: linux, boot, external-hard-drive

I installed Arch Linux on the second partition of my external hard drive and marked the partition as bootable in GParted, however it won't boot even if I select it from my BIOS' Boot Menu (it says "Non-system disk or disk error"). Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To boot the Linux kernel, you need a boot loader. There are multiple options, the most popular ones being:

- Grub
- Syslinux
- Lilo

There are some interesting newcomers though, especially for UEFI, especially Gummiboot. The Arch Linux Beginners' Guide contains a [chapter on setting up a boot loader](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide#Install_and_configure_a_bootloader).

Basically, it's something like this:

```
pacman -S grub
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```